# pls any one clear the error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server

```
alter function fz(@mdvn int,@fdate date,@tdate date)
returns @tabs table
(
    DVN int,
    PHC int,
    HSC int,
    ANC int,
    TT1 int,
    TTB int,
    IFA int,
    BP int,
    HB int
)
as
begin
declare @DVN int,@PHC int,@HSC int,@ANC int,@TT1 int,@TTB int,@IFA int,@BP int,@HB int
declare fnc cursor for
select dvn_cd,phc_cd,hsc_cd,sum(ANC1) as ANC,SUM(TT1) as TT1,sum(TTB2) as TT2,sum(IFA) as IFA,sum(BP1) as BP,sum(HB1) as HB from
(
select dvn_cd,phc_cd,hsc_cd,
    case when visit_no=3 and Visit_date between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0 end as ANC1,
    case when TTB=1 and TTDate between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0 end as TT1,
    case when TTB>1 and TTDate between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0 end as TTB2,
    case when IFA=100 and ANEDD between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0  end as IFA,     
    case when BP>='140/90' and ANEDD between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0  end as BP1,
    case when HB<11 and ANEDD between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0  end as HB1
from anvisits3 where dvn_cd=@mdvn and ANEDD between @fdate and @tdate
)a group by dvn_cd,phc_cd,hsc_cd
open fnc
    fetch next from fnc into @DVN,@PHC,@HSC,@ANC,@TT1,@TTB,@IFA,@BP,@HB 
    while @@fetch_status=0
    begin
        insert into @tabs
            select 'DVN'+convert(varchar(20),@DVN)+'PHC'+convert(varchar(20),@PHC)+'HSC'+convert(varchar(20),@HSC)+
            'ANC'+convert(varchar(20),@ANC)+'TT1'+Convert(varchar(20),@TT1)+'TTB'+convert(varchar(20),@TTB)+'IFA'+convert(varchar(20),@IFA)+
            'BP'+convert(varchar(20),@BP)+'HB'+convert(varchar(20),@HB)
        fetch next from fnc into @DVN,@PHC,@HSC,@ANC,@TT1,@TTB,@IFA,@BP,@HB 
    end
return
end
```

---

My error.
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fz, Line 33
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition
.

Comment: You're concatenating all of your values into a *single* string and then attempting to insert that into a table that has 9 int columns. It's not at all clear why you decided to perform that string concatenation in the first place, nor why you felt the need to use a cursor when you can just do `INSERT (<column list>) SELECT <rest of select query>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need:

```
alter function fz(@mdvn int,@fdate date,@tdate date)
returns @tabs table
(
    DVN int,
    PHC int,
    HSC int,
    ANC int,
    TT1 int,
    TTB int,
    IFA int,
    BP int,
    HB int
)
as
begin
insert into @tabs (DVN,PHC,HSC,ANC,TT1,TTB,IFA,BP,HB)
select dvn_cd,phc_cd,hsc_cd,sum(ANC1) as ANC,SUM(TT1) as TT1,sum(TTB2) as TT2,sum(IFA) as IFA,sum(BP1) as BP,sum(HB1) as HB from
(
select dvn_cd,phc_cd,hsc_cd,
    case when visit_no=3 and Visit_date between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0 end as ANC1,
    case when TTB=1 and TTDate between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0 end as TT1,
    case when TTB>1 and TTDate between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0 end as TTB2,
    case when IFA=100 and ANEDD between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0  end as IFA,     
    case when BP>='140/90' and ANEDD between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0  end as BP1,
    case when HB<11 and ANEDD between @fdate and @tdate then 1 else 0  end as HB1
from anvisits3 where dvn_cd=@mdvn and ANEDD between @fdate and @tdate
)a group by dvn_cd,phc_cd,hsc_cd
return
end
```

And by the way, unless you're somehow being charged by the letter, I'd seriously recommend using more expressive names for your columns (both here and in the base tables), unless these acronyms are ubiquitous in your industry.

Comment: but i should use cursor method.. kindly help me using cursor for that pgm

Comment: @user3068863 - *why* would you want to use a cursor here? cursors are usually best avoided unless you've exhausted all other solutions.

Comment: @user3068863: If you do insist on using a cursor, you've got enough information in this answer to fix the issue yourself, as the problem was mainly in how you were inserting data. This answer shows the right syntax to do that. However, unless you are doing an assignment on cursors, you really should not use a cursor here.

Answer (score 0):

The error message itself is clear: looks like you're trying to insert into `@tabs` result with more columns the table itself has. For example, you may have 10 columns in the table, but trying to insert 11.

Another reason: you're trying to insert `string` data into the column with type `integer`.

Answer (score 0):

hello no it's not a problem of string to integer the error is different.

I doubt it's coming from the insert or the order or error is strange :)

First you cannot do an insert inside a function. Function can only do select

Then i count the number of parameter for your cursor and number of your select it seems ok but it could come from there.
Why are you using a cursor? it makes no sense, do an insert based on a select and if it's easier to read use a with clause.

Example :

```
with p as (select * from mytableA)
insert into myTableB 
select * from myTableA
```

Oh yes sorry, it's the morning :) you can do this kind of insert but why are u still using a cursor and a temporary table when you can only do a single select? You have a lots of useless statement there :)